# How can pass multiline parameter into jenkins job

Tags: powershell, jenkins, groovy

I have a Powershell script with parameter that intended to be multiline, it's invoked from Jenkins job.

I want to pass multiline parameter from Jenkins to Powershell. When I just pass it unchanged, pipeline works but Powershell reads it as one string with no line break.

I split the multiline `FOLDERSACL` parameter, but now I can't pass it as the pipeline is failing because of type mismatch.

Please tell which type of param should i use?

```
def servers = env.SERVERLIST.split('\n')
def steps1 =[:]
def folders = env.FOLDERSACL.split('\n')
for (int i=0; i<servers.size(); i++) {
    def server = servers[i]
    def stepName = "running ${server}"
    steps1[stepName] = {->
        echo server
        def checkjob = build job: 'job', parameters: 
        [string(name: 'SERVERNAME', value: server), string(name: 'FOLDER', value: folder),string(name: 'USERNAME', value: env.USERNAME), string(name: 'FOLDERSACL', value: folders)]
        checklog = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName('job').getBuildByNumber(checkjob.getNumber()).log
        println checklog
    }
}

parallel steps1
```

Comment: could you provide a simple repeatable example of what you try to do. FYI: `split()` method returns an array - it's not a multiline string

Comment: I'm not familiar with Groovy, but I don't think Jenkins has an array parameter type. Even a multiline string is still a string, so I'd expect that you need to split it inside the (PowerShell) script.